# SELECT throwing an CAST error on a row that does not exist in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, casting, isnumeric

I'm having a problem with a SELECT that is throwing a CAST error, but only when the CAST is in the WHERE clause.   I've boiled the problem down to the below example SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CastTest (
[WhatIsThis] nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.CastTest (WhatIsThis) VALUES ('NotANumber');
INSERT INTO dbo.CastTest (WhatIsThis) VALUES ('11');
INSERT INTO dbo.CastTest (WhatIsThis) VALUES ('4');
SELECT *, CAST(WhatIsThis AS INT) ANumber 
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM dbo.CastTest WHERE ISNUMERIC(WhatIsThis)=1
        ) OnlyNumbers
      -- WHERE CAST(WhatIsThis AS INT)>10
```

The code above works, returning two rows where the NVARCHAR is CAST to a number, and excludes the other row where it is not a number.  But as soon as you uncomment the WHERE clause you get the following;

**Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'NotANumber' to data type int.**

Why is the CAST failing on a row that should not be visible to it?  What can I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `isnumeric()` for this purpose.  SQL in general does not guarantee the order of evaluation of clauses.  This includes subqueries and CTEs.  The operations can all be rearranged (and often are).

Instead, use `try_convert()` or `try_cast()` with an *explicit* conversion:

```
SELECT *, TRY_CAST(WhatIsThis AS INT) as ANumber 
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM dbo.CastTest
      WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, WhatIsThis) IS NOT NULL
     ) OnlyNumbers
```